# C++ lambda used in std::thread crash

Tags: c++, lambda, return, stdthread

This my code:

```
std::thread t([](){
  int ret = func();
  if (ret != 0){
    return false;
  }
});
t.detach();
```

As this code, compiler deduce the lambda return value type is bool, so when ret==0, the lambda has not a return value, then program is crash. Add return true can solve this problem, I want to now why?

I want to know, lambda return behavior when used in thread.

Comment: Not returning from a non-void function/lambda is undefined behavior.

Comment: Where is your `return true`? Also note using `detach` is almost always an error. Your thread will outlive main and cause lifetime issues. Ensure join is called before you exit main. (Or find some other cooperative cancellation method of your thread)

Comment: You want to know why well defined function works, while not well defined doesn't? Interesting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior Your code has undefined behavior, thats why it can crash.